# React: Render users based on customer id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this problem. I want to render the assigned user's username, based on what the customer id is.

It technically works, but doesn't work how i want it to work.

There's the assigned users object:

```
"assigneduser": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "customers_id": [
                2
            ],
            "username": "testuser"
        },
        {
            "user_id": 2,
            "customers_id": [
                3,
                4
            ],
            "username": "filanfisteku"
        }
    ]
```

I'm filtering assigned users based on the customers_id:

```
let assigneduserfilter = Object.values(assigneduser).filter(
    ({ customers_id }) => customers_id == i.id // i is the customers map
);
```

And then mapping assigneduserfilter:

```
{assigneduserfilter.map((z) => (
    <td key={z.customers_id}>{z.username}</td>                    
))}
```

How can i render the assigned user username on the relevant customer table row?

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty simple, so assuming you have an array of objects as follows

```
const arr = {
  assigneduser: [
    {
      user_id: 1,
      customers_id: [2],
      username: "testuser",
    },
    {
      user_id: 2,
      customers_id: [3, 4],
      username: "filanfisteku",
    },
  ],
};
```

You would proceed by creating a function to find your customer as seen below.

```
const assgnedUserFilter = (user) => {
  return arr.assigneduser.find((u) => u.customers_id == user);
};
```

Then call the function with the customer_id you want to find. Then manually map the values to your HTML.

```
const selectedCustomer = assgnedUserFilter(2);

<p id="customer_id">{selectedCustomer.customer_id}</p>

<p id="username">{selectedCustomer.username}</p>
```